# Is there another way to troubleshoot libpq/gyp errors with Netlify build errors?

Tags: typescript, serverless, netlify

This is a shot in the dark but I'm past beating a dead horse here.

I'm trying to deploy a typescript-based serverless application to Netlify.

When I run the application locally using `netlify dev`, which runs things fine, connects to a Postgres database I have running on Railway, all that jazz.

When I try to deploy to Netlify's site though, I consistently get a series of build errors relating to `libpq` and `gyp`.

[This](https://%20https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/2069) is the same issue, which was resolved by deleting the package-lock and node modules, then re-running`npm i`.

[This is also](https://answers.netlify.com/t/build-failing-with-gyp-error/44167/15) the same issue, which was not resolved, but was suggested to be solved by installing postgresql-dev.

[Here again is the same issue](https://answers.netlify.com/t/prebuild-node-gyp-error/46704), which was resolved by setting the Node version on Netlify to 14.17.5.

[This a similar issue](https://answers.netlify.com/t/prebuild-node-gyp-error/46704) (same error code, different package), which was also resolved by using the most recent stable version of node at the time.

First me, then a coworker, have each independently tried those solutions to no effect, still receiving the build errors. Based on some tinkering, we think the fact that this is a typescript project may be related... a non-typescript project was able to be deployed just fine. But that is just our best guess at this point, looking for any possible solutions.

Here's the build failure message:

```bash
6:52:23 PM: Build ready to start
6:52:25 PM: build-image version: 9289b698a503f132b265bd089ab40ce1d6f9e65e (focal)
6:52:25 PM: build-image tag: v4.12.0
6:52:25 PM: buildbot version: c87074660cd9a4568c0ac759bc083987e94204b3
6:52:26 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
6:52:26 PM: Starting to download cache of 2.3KB
6:52:26 PM: Finished downloading cache in 52.739394ms
6:52:26 PM: Starting to extract cache
6:52:26 PM: Finished extracting cache in 3.09226ms
6:52:26 PM: Finished fetching cache in 121.710237ms
6:52:26 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
6:52:26 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/main
6:52:26 PM: Parsing package.json dependencies
6:52:27 PM: Different functions path detected, going to use the one specified in the Netlify configuration file: 'functions' versus '' in the Netlify UI
6:52:27 PM: Starting build script
6:52:27 PM: Installing dependencies
6:52:27 PM: Python version set to 2.7
6:52:28 PM: Downloading and installing node v14.17.5...
6:52:28 PM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.5/node-v14.17.5-linux-x64.tar.xz...
6:52:28 PM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
6:52:28 PM: Checksums matched!
6:52:30 PM: Now using node v14.17.5 (npm v6.14.14)
6:52:30 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
6:52:30 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
6:52:30 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
6:52:30 PM: Using ruby version 2.7.2
6:52:31 PM: Using PHP version 8.0
6:52:31 PM: No npm workspaces detected
6:52:31 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
6:52:31 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
6:52:31 PM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 6.14.14
6:52:36 PM: > libpq@1.8.12 install /opt/build/repo/node_modules/libpq
6:52:36 PM: > node-gyp rebuild
6:52:39 PM: find: ‘/usr/pg*’: No such file or directory
6:52:39 PM: gyp: Call to 'which pg_config || find /usr/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/pg* /opt -executable -name pg_config -print -quit' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
6:52:39 PM: gyp ERR! configure error
6:52:39 PM: gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
6:52:39 PM: gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/opt/buildhome/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
6:52:39 PM: gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
6:52:39 PM: gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
6:52:39 PM: gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.196-108.356.amzn2.x86_64
6:52:39 PM: gyp ERR! command "/opt/buildhome/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/bin/node" "/opt/buildhome/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
6:52:39 PM: gyp ERR! cwd /opt/build/repo/node_modules/libpq
6:52:39 PM: gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.5
6:52:39 PM: gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
6:52:39 PM: gyp ERR! not ok
6:52:39 PM: npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
6:52:39 PM: npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
6:52:39 PM: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
6:52:39 PM: npm ERR! errno 1
6:52:39 PM: npm ERR! libpq@1.8.12 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
6:52:39 PM: npm ERR! Exit status 1
6:52:39 PM: npm ERR!
6:52:39 PM: npm ERR! Failed at the libpq@1.8.12 install script.
6:52:39 PM: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
6:52:39 PM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
6:52:39 PM: npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2022-10-11T01_52_39_917Z-debug.log
6:52:39 PM: Error during NPM install
6:52:39 PM: Build was terminated: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
6:52:39 PM: Creating deploy upload records
6:52:40 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
6:52:40 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
6:52:40 PM: Finished processing build request in 14.377988447s
```